# Prevent TextView from wrapping in parent

Tags: android, textview

How do I prevent a TextView, or any visual object, from wrapping to the screen and instead have them chopped off the sides? Is there some XML attribute or code to do this or is it impossible to have anything overflow from the screen?

For example, you have this:

[image: text being wrapped]

But you really want this:

[image: text being cropped]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

check out `android:maxLines="1"` and if you want to add ending `...` add also `android:ellipsize="end"`

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/name"
   android:text="i want this to crop not wrap"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:ellipsize="end" />
```

`android:singleLine="true"` was [deprecated in API Level 3](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine).

Comment: @Pentium10: Nice, thanks. How would this be done for buttons and stuff though?

Comment: Huh. Probably the same way. There is not much you can do about them beyond what I just showed. You use the height and width stuff to limit the view, and the rest will be cut off.

Comment: This would cause a `...` appearance at the end of the line.

Comment: R.attr.singleLine was deprecated in API 3 but android:singleLine has **never** been deprecated for TextView. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine causes any much to written as will fill the line. maxLines=1 will cause only up to the last full word to be written to the line.

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for `android:singleLine="true"`.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales Nowhere does it say `singleLine` is deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine

Comment: While IntelliJ indicates that android:singleLine is deprecated, it doesn't appear to be according to the Documentation (as of API 27). And in fact it has different behaviour to maxLines=1 as it causes as much text as fills the TextView to be displayed, whereas maxLines=1 truncates after the last full word that can be written.

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked out [android:scrollHorizontally](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:scrollHorizontally). There is also a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

And in java code it's:

```
textView.setSingleLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

`textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);` worked for me.