# How to Disable Word-wrap in Android Multiline TextView?

Tags: android, textview, line-breaks, word-wrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Disable Word Wrap in an Android Multi-Line TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146207/disable-word-wrap-in-an-android-multi-line-textview)

I have a question about Android TextView.
Is it possible to disable word-wrap in multiline TextView?

I want to use Multiline TextView like following:

> apple orange apple oran
>
> ge apple orange apple o
>
> range

But actual TextView is following:

> apple orange apple
>
> orange apple orange
>
> apple orange apple
>
> orange apple orange

I want to feed new line JUST 23byte.

Answer (score 1):

try to fix size of width, may be this work.

Comment: @George: The possible thread which you have marked as duplicate to this is not really a duplicate. The answer in that thread is to assign "singleLine=true" property to the textview or to enable horizontal scrolling. The question asked in this thread is about maintaining multiline, without horizontal scrolling but disable word wrapping. Even I an looking for the solution to this problem.