# Problems with horizontal scroll on multi line textview on android

Tags: android, textview, horizontal-scrolling

I have problems with horizontal scrolls bars. I am displaying information similar to a log in a textview.

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:layout_height="2dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/receive_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:layout_height="2dp" />
```

[image]

I need all the information to be aligned to the timestamp but I am not achieving it.

Thank you in advance for helping me

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here !

[Disable Word Wrap in an Android Multi-Line TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146207/disable-word-wrap-in-an-android-multi-line-textview)

```
setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean)
```

It's ok for me.

Thanks !