# How to perform TranslateAnimation of textView that is larger than the view

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout that contains a few textViews and buttons.  The text in the textView is larger than the view.  My desire is to perform a TranslateAnimation on these textviews to have them scroll in from the right at a quick speed and then exit the left.

The problem is that if the text is initially *bigger* than the view, the text gets cropped.  I first looked at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507798/stop-objects-from-wrapping-in-android), but the text gets cropped.  I have made the text scrollable, and that works.  However, it depends on the user to actually scroll it.  I also tried a marquee, but it just doesn't have the effect I want.

Here is part of the code for the layout:

```
          <TextView
         android:text="@string/try_your"
         android:id="@+id/textView2" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
         android:paddingBottom="25dip"         
         android:textSize="24sp" 
         android:textStyle="bold"      
         android:singleLine = "true" 
     />
```

Here is the code for the TranslateAnimation:

```
public void performLineAnimation1(int fade) {

    View think_you = findViewById(R.id.textView4);              
    TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(600.0f, -400.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


    slide.setDuration(7000);
    think_you.startAnimation(slide);
            
    ((TextView) think_you).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    
    //slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    
}
```

I've even tried to "trick" it by having the onDraw method draw the textView at a lot smaller pixels (sp) and then enlarging it later, but that doesn't work.

TranslateAnimation has the effects that I want, but I just can't get this to work. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Rick

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's what I did,

I changed the layout code to:

```
    <TextView
         android:text=""
         android:id="@+id/textView2" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:paddingTop="25dp"
         android:paddingBottom="100dp"         
         android:textSize="12sp" 
         android:singleLine = "true" 
         android:scrollHorizontally="true"
         android:textColor="@color/clear"
     />
```

And the java code to:

```
        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translatescale);   
        Think_you.startAnimation(a);
    a.setFillAfter(true);`
```

translatescale.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="-120%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="10000"
    android:zAdjustment="top" />
<scale

    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:duration="3"></scale>        

</set>
```

So, what I did was kind of clugy...  I made the text size small so that it would fit within the view that it was going to be displayed in. I then used an animation set to perform a scale and a TranslateAnimation.  I made the scale animation make the text to the desired size that I wanted and I had it perform extremely fast (3 mS) and then perform the translateAnimation like I wanted. These works, but seems rather clugy.  But I couldn't find another way to do it - doing a marquee, making something scrollable - didn't seem to do it.

If anybody has another solution, I wouldn't mind hearing it.

There is however a quick glitch in the right part of the screen before it animates, but I'm willing to live with that.

Thanks,

Rick