# Fit TextView text on one line with WRAP_CONTENT LayoutParams

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, word-wrap

Say I have a `TextView` with some dynamic text. This `TextView` is being placed inside a `LinearLayout` with `WRAP_CONTENT` LayoutParams for both width & height.

Problem is that some of the text is - breaking onto second(or third) line - wrapping. I want to avoid this.

I have tried to replace all ' '(space chars) with non-breaking space character. This hasn't helped. The text still breaks. I also cannot set the `TextView's` maxLines=1 because there are some newline chars in the String-data.

I am not sure if any code samples need to be included. If there;s something specific, please do ask me in a comment.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :~)

Comment: check out [this][1] answer to a similar question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507798/stop-objects-from-wrapping-in-android

Comment: @JoeB. Hi Joe, thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to ellipsize the text if its long. I would like the container(in this case, a LinearLayout) to expand and accommodate the TextView's width. I am not sure how to go about this. Can you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giving the `TextView` [the attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) `android:singleLine="true"` will constrain the text to a single horizontally scrolling line instead of letting it wrap onto multiple lines. Without the `android:ellipsize` attribute, the text will be horizontally scrollable if it doesn't all fit on the screen. With the `android:layout_width="wrap content"` attribute given to the `TextView`'s parent layout, it should resize itself accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

@Joe B. Answer is right. but `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated. You need to use

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for

```
android:singleLine="true"
```